# Why can't I get the URL from the hyperlink on this web page?

Tags: python

I tried to extract URL from a hyperlink in this web: https://etherscan.io/tokens

I used the following Python code:

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = 'https://etherscan.io/tokens'
grab = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(grab.text, 'html.parser')

# opening a file in write mode
f = open("test1.txt", "w")
# traverse paragraphs from soup
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    data = link.get('href')
    f.write(data)
    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

The problem is this code does not return any URL. There is only error:
https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing

I used VScode under W10.

Comment: Cloudflare does what it is supposed to do, it "blocks" your request.

Comment: is there any workaround?